# Statistically significant differences, when sample is not normal.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have two sample which doesn't comes from normally distributions. How to analyse whether there are statistically significant differences ?

Comment: There are **very many** ways for a distribution to be **not normal**.  You wouldnt expect us to be able to say much about a number from tha fact that **it is no zero**, and your question is equivalent. Please augment!

Answer (score 2):

In special situations, you can still do *exact* inference. However, if you're looking for general approaches, then you can try:

1. Nonparametric tests and confidence intervals (there are TONS of methods in this class that do not depend on normality)
2. Bootstrapping (parametric or nonparametric)
3. Likelihood-iterval-based
4. Bayesian inference

So, you have a lot of areas to look into. Normal-based stats is "classical" stats, and these have been shown to be broadly useful even when the underlying distribution is known to be very non-normal.